# How do I mount a disk on /var/log directory even if I have process writing on it?

Tags: mount, partition, logs, disk, high-availability

I would like to mount a disk on /var/log, the thing is, there are some process/services writing into it, such as openvpn, or system logs. Is there a way to mount a filesystem without having to restart the machine, or stopping the service?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can mount a new device on top of /var/log but the applications using the old mount point open files will continue writing to them.

I'd recommend that you reboot into recovery mode, backup /var/log, mount a new device and restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, depending on your services.

First: you can mount the new file system over the old one. But the running processes will continue to write to the old `/var/log`. You can force a logrotate, which will probably make many services and processes log to the new partition.  But you will not free the space under `/var/log` on the old partition. And you will need to look if all logs are really on the new partition.

Although it is possible, you should probably reboot the machine. If your system is Linux, I recommend booting from a live image (USB, DVD, ...) and do the changes from that system (including moving the old logs to the new partition). For other UNIX systems, you may need to boot into maintenance mode or something like that.